# If I want a subtype to only be deriveable from a single Supertype, should I be using abstract classes intead of an interface to ensure that?

Tags: java, types, interface, abstract-class

Basically the question in the title but here a little more detail:
I have a set of classes you can create similar objects of (e.g. animals and I have the classes Tiger, Crocodile, Wolf etc. whatever you like). And the types of those objects are specified by the Supertype they are derived from. Now some objects might derive from multiple Supertypes, which obviously need to be implemented as Interfaces. But lets say I have a specific Supertype which I want each animal to only derive EXACTLY ONCE from (e.g. the animal family they belong to). Does this automatically mean that this Supertype should be an abstract class to ensure it can only be extended once in a Subtype?

Edit since Michael pointed out that my question is unclear.

This question is not about a specific piece of code it is more a theoretical question about types, maybe I should ask like this: Can and should an abstract class be used as a tool to ensure a Subtype of this Supertype can only derive it once. Lets say for my example with animals I have the Supertypes "Omnivore", "Herbivore" and "Carnivore" and I know an animal can only be exactly one of those, is this a valid reason to make those abstract classes and not interfaces?

Comment: The question is unclear. Show, don't tell. Demonstrate your problem in code

Answer (score 1):

If you have different **exclusive categories** then different base classes (abstract or not) is a sensible solution.

```
class HerbivoreBase implements Animal, EatsVegetables { ... }
class CarnivoreBase implements Animal, EatsAnimals { ... }
class OmnivoreBase implements Animal, EatsVegetables, EatsAnimals { ... }
```

It only makes sense when the classes have (differing) methods.

To look at other languages. **Scala** has *case classes* (the name says it all) with pattern matching.
Java also has (will have?) pattern matching based on classes, and instanceof as follows:

```
Animal animal = ...
if (animal instanceof Herbivore herbi) { ... herbi.eatVegy(...); ... }
else if (animal instanceof Carnivore carni) { ... carni.hunts(...); ... }
```

Java has also introduced a restricting mechanism to list which classes may be child of a given class, say abstract class `Animal`.

*I would still like to mention, that modeling with inheritance can easily over-architect things, especially if later a change is needed, or the code becomes bloated.*

Answer (score 0):

An interface is a way to define signature of a method, but *normally* it does not define the implementation of a given method. If you want to implement a method in an interface, use the **default** keyword

```
interface inter{
   public default void myMethod(){/*your code here*/
}
```

A class can implement multiple *interfaces* but cannot extend more than one class.

If you are using an abstract class you are can use the following two *benefits*

1. The abstract class **cannot be initialized**
2. The abstract class can implement *abstract* methods.

A subclass can still only extend one class, abstract or not.

Your question was: "If I want a **superclass** to only be derivable from a single **subclass**, which should I use? Interface or abstract class?"

By derivable, do you mean inheritance? Because if that's the case, then I think you got the question backwards. Subclasses inherit from the superclasses.

The child (subclass) inherits from its parent (superclass)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is more about "should I use an interface, or a class (and extend it)?"

Remember that a subclass has a relationship of **is-a** with its base class. A class has a relationship of **has-a** with an interface.
An interface define a behaviour that one class has (a car **has** 4 wheels) (remember also that an interface should define only one behaviour, related to the interface segregation principle, which says that it's better to have more smaller and specific interfaces than one general and bigger, so that classes can implements only needed behaviours), a superclass define a "more general" type (dog **is** an animal).

See for example:

If you have a **MountainBike** class, it will implement an interface **Bike**, or extend a class **Bike**? It will **extend** the Bike class, since mountain bike is a "sub-type" of bike.

If you have an **Elephant** class, it will implement an interface **Trunk** or extend a class **Trunk**? It will **implement** the Trunk interface, since trunk is a part (behaviour) of the elephant, not a "container".